# Select group of users in approval process

Tags: approval-process

I want to create approval process in which I send mail request to group of users depending on submitter. For example if submitter is assigned a territory or organization unit (an object in our app), then approver shold be from that organization unit only. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this objective is to use custom User lookup fields on the object-being-approved

You would use a trigger or workflow/process builder to set the values of these User lookup fields based on territory or organization unit. Then, your approval process can route to Step 1 assigned approver a related User(s). In the example below, I have a custom User lookup field called `Level1Approver__c`

[image]

Comment: Thanks I already have that idea but what if I have group of users? can I create a queue by passing users from a long text area with ids separated by some separater.

Comment: @AnilkumarGorantala - regrettably not that I know of. Use multiple lookup fields User1__c, User2__c, etc and populate with the set of possible approvers